# Knockout validation throttle

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi i have a css binding on a input type which adds the class CircleErrors if it matches my function. My problem is it has a delay on taking the class off it only happens when i tab off the input box. I want the class to be removed on key down of the keyboard.. i know there is a throttle you can use for knockout but i am not sure how to go about doing it.

```
<input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First name" data-bind="value: Registration.FirstName, css: { CircleErrors: Registration.FirstName().length == 0 && Registration.FirstNameValidation(), valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' }">
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rqk4kckc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misplaced your `valueUpdate` parameter.  It's inside the `css` parameter - you need to move it outside the `}`:

```
<input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First name" data-bind="value: Registration.FirstName, css: { CircleErrors: Registration.FirstName().length == 0 && Registration.FirstNameValidation() }, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
```

[Here's a demo with it working](http://jsfiddle.net/rqk4kckc/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the textInput binding instead of the value binding for the first name property (and for any text input fields for that matter). To quote the docs

> Unlike the value binding, textInput provides instant updates from the
>   DOM for all types of user input, including autocomplete,
>   drag-and-drop, and clipboard events.

You don't need the valueUpdate binding any more, however it was inside your CSS binding so would not have had any effect.

```
<input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First name" data-bind="textInput: Registration.FirstName, css: { CircleErrors: Registration.FirstName().length == 0 && Registration.FirstNameValidation() }">
```

Comment: I was trying to get the `textInput` binding working as an alternative for my answer, but [couldn't do so](http://jsfiddle.net/7un80p6h/1/).  Any ideas why?  It's not one I've used before.

Comment: jsfiddle is using knockout 3.0.0 whereas the textInput binding was added in 3.2.0

Comment: Ah thanks, that explains both why it wasn't working and why I've not used it before :)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rqk4kckc/4/)

this is what you looking for
` var reg = new (function() {
    var self = this;
    this.FirstName = ko.observable('');
        this.checkifEmpty = ko.observable(false);

```
this.check=function(){
    if(this.FirstName()!=null&&this.FirstName()!=undefined &&     this.FirstName() !=''){
     this.checkifEmpty(true);
    }else{
             this.checkifEmpty(false);

    }
}
this.FirstNameValidation = function() {
    return true;
}
```

})();

ko.applyBindings(reg);

`